# Transistor as Bipolar Switch NPN BJT - Cutoff and Saturation not working

Tags: switches, bjt, voltage-divider

I have a Transistor as a NPN BJT bipolar switch - Cutoff and saturation. With load on the emitter to measure a voltage divider. The voltage that reaches the base is 3.3 V and the collector voltage is 24 V.

But it's not working for me. All of the voltage remains sitting between the collector and emitter when it goes into saturation mode. If you have a solution or if it is poorly designed, a hand would be of great help.

[image]

Possible solution:

[image]

Comment: That's an NPN transistor.

Comment: True, I modified it there.

Comment: In that case, you're using it wrong. You can't switch a load on the emitter of a transistor (at least without complicated drive circuitry).

Comment: @JoséVicenteR Describe what you want to achieve. I do get that \$V_{_\text{IN}}=24\:\text{V}\$ and that that control line is either \$0\:\text{V}\$ or else \$3.3\:\text{V}\$.  What does \$V_{_\text{BAT}}\$ do? What accepts it? What does the receiving circuit expect to see? The BJT should, in your circuit as shown, always be in *active mode* and never *saturated mode*. Don't you see why? There's no way I can criticize your circuit as I don't know what you need at the output, or why.

Comment: @periblepsis Vin = 24V 
Vbat/Control 0V or 3.3v,
For:
0V -> Vbat should be 0V (cut off)
3.3V -> Vbat will be the result of the voltage divider of Vin (in saturation).

Comment: @JoséVicenteR Tell me how you imagine the bjt will be saturated.

Comment: @periblepsis the transistor is in saturation when the collector-emitter voltage is zero VCE=0, so the voltage divider of R35 and R36 should be seeing Vin.

Comment: @JoséVicenteR But it's not possible for the collector-emitter voltage to be zero in the circuit you've drawn, unless VBAT/CONTROL is higher than VIN.

Comment: @Hearth ok then I should use then it is a PNP with Vin to the emitter.

Comment: @JoséVicenteR Yes, but if you want to be able to switch it with a low voltage VBAT/CONTROL, you'll need to add an additional transistor to level-shift things. It's very common to use an NPN transistor and a couple resistors to drive a PNP high-side switch.

Comment: @Hearth ok, thanks for the information, another solution could use the arrangement that of the second image that I added. At the output of Q2 add the voltage divider.

Comment: @JoséVicenteR That's exactly the PNP-and-NPN arrangement I mentioned, just using a P-channel MOSFET instead of a PNP bipolar. That would work fine.

Comment: @JoséVicenteR You haven't explained to me how it comes to pass that VCE = 0. When you do make that explanation, I'll read it and criticize it. But until then, all I see is active mode.